# How to make Desktop app with Electron js and Vue offline, having server side Laravel?

Tags: vue.js, electron, offline, desktop

I am trying to build a desktop application which needs to be offline. Database transaction needs to be offline and there must be offline syncing. Through my research, I found sqlite and pouchdb.
Can anyone suggest me the best option?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to make an electron app that uses vue and vuex. All the things that need to happen (database transactions) will first be sent to the localstorage.

If the user is connected to the internet you'd send the transactions to the server. If the user isn't connected to the internet the transactions will be saved in localstorage until the point where the user comes back online.

Then you just make a setInterval that checks the store every x seconds for updates that just makes the http calls to laravel you want to make.

I think this can give you a push in the right direction:
https://www.mikestreety.co.uk/blog/vue-js-using-localstorage-with-the-vuex-store